# Phonegap/cordova inappbrowser executescript as soon as dom is ready

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I want to inject some code in my inappbrowser but don't want to wait until the entire page and all images (can be a lot) is loaded, so I wanted to use the loadstart event instead on the loadstop event.

Since this event is fired before the browser has even changed to the new url and the dom is ready I want to keep checking the url and readystate untill I can inject my code. But after the setTimeout to try it again it stops... what am I doing wrong, or is there a better way to get my script injected as soon as the dom is ready? thanks!

```
browser = window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank','transitionstyle=fliphorizontal,toolbar=no,location=no');
browser.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstart);

var requestedURL = '';

function getUrl() {
   browser.executeScript({code:"window.location.href"}, checkUrl);
}

function checkUrl(respons) {

   if (respons[0] == requestedURL)
   {
           getReadyState();
   } else {
           setTimeout(getUrl,500);
   }
}

function getReadyState() {
   browser.executeScript({code:"document.readyState"}, checkReadyState);
}

function checkReadyState(respons) {

   if (respons[0] == 'interactive' || respons[0] == 'complete')
   {
           browser.executeScript({file:"http://www.example.com/script.js"});
   } else {
           setTimeout(getReadyState,500);
   }
}

function loadstart (event) {
requestedURL = event.url;
browser.executeScript({code:"window.location.href"}, checkUrl);
}
```